# Why is Django Paramaterized query not working

Tags: django, django-models

I have been struggling with this simple query in django. I have checked a lot over internet. I tried using similar syntax - yet no luck.

In my application on html page I need to display some specific record. And for that i want to use parameterized select statement. But the query is not working..

I have checked id2 is getting correct value from previous html page..

And I know I can use APIs but for my databases classes I need to use raw queries in my application.

Can someone please help me here...

```
def details(request, id2):

     temp = 'test3'   
     data = Posts.objects.raw('''select * from posts_posts where posts_posts.id = %s ''', id2)      
     context ={
          'post' : data,
```

Comment: Hi, it's not clear for me what's your issue actually.

Comment: Hi..I am trying to fecth data from postgresql and print that on html page.However the query is not working correctly. No data is getting selected. The simple select query is working fine but this parameterized query is not working correctly.

Comment: This is completely pointless. There's no need for a raw query here. You should do `Post.objects.filter(id=2)`.

Comment: yes i agree... as i already mentioned in my original post...this assignmnet is for my database management class...i cannot use direct APIs... I am supposed to use raw queries...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run that code you will see an error, since that is not the correct format for a call to `raw`.  If you can't see the error output anywhere, then you have yet another problem for another post.

The correct format for raw is: `.raw(sql, iterable-values)`, like this:

```
posts = Posts.objects.raw("select * ..", [id2, ])  # or use (id2,) for a tuple
<RawQuerySet: select * from ... where id = 5>
```

To get the actual list, since that just gives you a Query, you need to evaluate it somehow:

```
posts_list = list(posts)
first_post = posts[0]
```

Be careful, if you don't evaluate the `QuerySet` then it can be re-run a second time.  Please convert it to a list() before doing further operations on it.

Comment: thanks a ton...your suggestion to evaluate the query helped. :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please remember to upvote questions you find helpful, and make any responses as "answered" if they solve your issue.